# Is there a way to let non-technical individuals utilize BigQuery reports?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want to have an access port for non-tech savvy individuals in which they could make reports of their own without needing to know SQL what-so-ever.
It would be best if I could create custom fields of myself, and then just let the users in the access port pick and choose whichever they like with a custom date range.

I've explored the options Google Data Studio offers, but it looks to me like it mostly puts an emphasis on data visualization.
In addition, my attempts to make custom queries with it were not successful, since the platform is rigid in terms of deciding which field is a metric and which is a dimension (and it does so inaccurately). This makes it hard to query reports as you normally would using BigQuery, which doesn't have these somewhat arbitrary limitations.
Perhaps I've misunderstood something about the platform due to my limited experience with it, but it looks like Data Studio isn't going to fit the bill for me.

EDIT: In addition, the platform should have a way of exporting said reports as CSV files, a feature that Data Studio doesn't have as far as I know.

It would be great to receive suggestions for a different platform which would better fit my needs, or even suggestions on how to make better use of Data Studio.

Comment: Data Studio is a good tool. Additionally, you may try tableau or chart.io as alternatives, but both are paid

Comment: As Shamshad says, there are plenty solutions - some open source, and some for a higher price. Can you share more about your situation? (Maybe in http://reddit.com/r/BigQuery, if stack overflow rejects this as a non technical question)

Comment: As I said, I'm not extremely familiar with the Data Studio platform, but from my trials I couldn't get the results I wanted because of the rigid classification of dimension and metric.
If there's a solution to this issue, it would be great.

I'll be happy to share more information, just not sure what there is more to say.
If you have any specific questions I'll answer them.

Comment: just my two cents, stay away from Data studio, until they implement calculated metrics, it is not very useful, right now all you can do is calculated fields which operate only at the row level. creating a simple table with total and percent complete by category is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using a tool like redash (https://redash.io)? Assuming your GA360 data is in BigQuery you can connect redash to BQ. Then you can author queries and visualize.

You can also use the Google Could SDK to connect to BQ and run custom queries to generate new tables in BQ based on the GA360 session data. Then use redash, or any tool, to report/visualize.